# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' FLASK

Tags: python, html, image, flask, computer-vision

I upload an image file using Flask Python. I passed this input image file to a class as an argument, this class returns an Output Image. I want to save that output file to static folder and display that Output Image. But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I really don't understand this error as I have passed the image argument correctly to a class. Following is the Flask code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask.views import MethodView
from files.testmain import CocoDataset

app=Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

class ImageUpload(MethodView):

    def post(self):
        target=os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/images/')
        print(target)

        if not os.path.isdir(target):
            os.mkdir(target)

        file=request.files['file']
        print(file)
        print(type(file))
        fileInput=file.filename
        print(fileInput)
        print(type(fileInput))
        coco=CocoDataset(fileInput)
        image=coco.detection()
        filename='detection.jpg'
        image.save('static/images/'+filename)
        #print(file)
        print(type(filename))

        return render_template('index.html', upload=True, filename=filename, target=target)


app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=ImageUpload.as_view('homepage'))

app.run(debug=True)
```

CocoDataset Class:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

class CocoDataset:

    def __init__(self, img):
        self.img = img

    def detection(self):
        net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3-spp.cfg',
                                         'yolov3-spp.weights')


        with open('coco.names', 'r') as f:
            classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

        #print(type(self.img))
        my_img = cv2.imread(self.img)
        print(my_img)
        print(my_img.shape)
        my_img = cv2.resize(my_img, (800, 800))
        #my_img.shape
        wt, ht, _ = my_img.shape  # width, height, channel

       #some code for detection
       #__________________#

       im = Image.fromarray(my_img)
       return im
```

The error seems to say that `my_img` in **CocoDataset** class is `NoneType` whereas it has to be an Image i.e. Numpy Array, I guess. What is the correct way to pass an image as an argument in this case. I am a beginner in Flask so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NoneType means none, so `my_img = cv2.imread(self.img)` is returning None, ie nothing. That's why it can't see the attribute shape.

I am not familiar with the libraries you've listed but reading what you've posted you would instantiate a class of type CocoDataset by just typing `your_instance_name = CocoDataset(whatever_your_image_is)`.

```
def __init__(self, img):
    self.img = img
```

^ That's the constructor, and it takes one argument and that's img.

Edit: Sorry, I am familiar with flask, but I glanced over your code a bit too fast.

Maybe the file isn't getting the the Constructor. See here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/

```
file = request.files['file']
        # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
        # empty file without a filename.
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
```

Comment: I tried it but this did not work. I am already passing the image file to the class. I am not sure what the problem is. I think passing `file.filename` argument to the class is not doing the trick, it is just returning NoneType whereas Class accepts the path of the image. I know we can't access paths using Flask, so anyway to get over this. Much appreciated

Comment: Does flask flash 'No selected file'?

Comment: You can pass paths using pathlib Path. Just checked and it works in flask :) 

from pathlib import Path
mypath = Path("/static/images/bill.jpg")